# caretEnsemble failing with is(all.models, "caretList") is not TRUE

Tags: r, r-caret, ensemble-learning

I've tried the code of zachmayer from https://gist.github.com/zachmayer/5152157, but I got an error "is(all.models, "caretList") is not TRUE", when running caretEnsemble command. Should I use caretList instead of just making a list of all the models? Thanks.

```
`#Train some models  
model1 <- train(X[train,], Y[train], method='gbm', trControl=myControl,
            tuneGrid=expand.grid(.n.trees=500, .interaction.depth=15,.shrinkage = 0.01))
model2 <- train(X[train,], Y[train], method='blackboost', trControl=myControl)
...
#Make a list of all the models  
all.models <- list(model1, model2, model3, model4, model5, model6, model7, model8, model9, model10)

#Make a greedy ensemble
 greedy <- caretEnsemble(all.models, iter=1000L)
Error: is(all.models, "caretList") is not TRUE`
```

Comment: can you share your traincontrol function. By the way it does not support timeslices method of cross validation

Comment: Hi instead of list to ensemble model you should use caretList

Comment: Thanks! I think so. I should use "careList" instead of just a model list. But when doing model ensemble, it's more convenient to make a list than running all the model together in "caretList".

Comment: **Post your complete code including `myControl`**, to make this reproducible. Even if you used unmodified the same one as Zach used in his gist at that URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use general function`c()`

For reference : https://rdrr.io/cran/caretEnsemble/man/c.caretList.html

P.S. Also in `fitControl()` you have to set `savePredictions = TRUE`